# Hide(not delete) the checkbox in Blueimp jquery fileupload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, file-upload, blueimp

### The requirement:-

I have successfully implemented the Blueimp Jquery Fileupload plugin.
Now, when I upload a file, I get a checkboz alongside the Delete button.

How can I hide the checkbox(I mean just make it invisible but actually present).

I have attached an image to mean what I say:-
[image]

**How can I hide the checkbox?**

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with CSS:

```
<style>#fileupload input.toggle{display: none}</style>
```